# What are the best practices on server-side validation with django-backbone app?

Tags: django, django-models, backbone.js, django-forms

Trying to make single-page application using backbone and django on a server-side.

Validating with Django's ModelForm does not look great for that purpose because of nested models and difficulties in showing an error message to a user in a proper place.

Is there any good practices to validate model's properties in Django and show it on a page for a single-page application?

Answer (score 3):

We have a single page app in production with this exact setup, using a modified backbone.js and django-rest-framework.

We use ModelForm validation through the DRF Resource (checkout [DRF](http://django-rest-framework.org/) if you want to setup an API for a single page app, it's very straight forward and customizable). When using nested models, we bind one model per view and handle the saves separately, first we save the main model and upon success of that save, we save the nested models, each with separate error handling.

On the backbone-side we have a special FormView that handles the rendering of the form, error-handling, etc. It has a ´submit´-method that serializes the form and saves the data to the model, looking somewhat like this (we have a bit more sanitychecking logic that I stripped out, this is not our exact code, more very javascript-like pseudocode that might even run :))

```
FormView = Backbone.View.extend({

// ... left out functionality for rendering, serializing, etc

submit: function(){
    var data = form.serialize();
    var self = this;

    self.clearErrors();
    self.model.save(data,{
        success: function(model, response){
            self.showSuccess(response) // displays a save-success message
        },
        error: function(model, response){
            self.showError($.parseJSON(response.responseText)) //displays errors
        }
    })
},

clearErrors: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.$("ul.non-field-errors").empty() // Clear the main form error list
    _.each(self.fields, function(field){
       self.$("ul.field-errors#field-" + field.name + "]").empty();
    });
},

showErrors: function(errors){
    /*
     Errors are given by DRF as a dict:
     {
         errors: [error1, error2, ...], // form level errors
         field-errors: {  // field level errors
             field_name1 : [error1, error2, ...],
             field_name2 : [error1, error2, ...],
         }
     }
    */
    var self = this;
    self.$("ul.form-errors").empty() // Clear the main form error list
    _.each(errors.non-field-errors, function(error){
        self.$("ul.errors").append("<li>"+error+"</li>");
    });
    _.each(errors.field-errors, function(error, field_name){
        _.each(error, function(err){
           self.$("ul.field-errors#field-" + field_name + "]").append("<li>"+error+"</li>");
        });
    });
}

});
```

On the django side, DRF can handle it pretty well for you if you use a ModelResource and ModelForm validation.